# Expo-In-App_Purchases library giving me Cannot read property '__expo_module_name__' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play-console

I ran this command
npx expo install expo-in-app-purchases

then I wrote this API
import * as InAppPurchases from 'expo-in-app-purchases';

but these processes are giving me this error

ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property '**expo_module_name**' of undefined, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I tried installing npm many times
Also Npx expo start -clear

Comment: Development of `expo-in-app-purchases` is currently paused to focus on other projects. Alternative libraries include `react-native-iap` and `react-native-purchases` from RevenueCat, https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/.

Comment: @user16967562 Which library should I go with? For android device you used these libraries before? can you contact me goktugfevziozcelik @ gmail . com